# How to blend tone mapping noise into an image without a patch effect?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I would like to create tone mapping (including contrast change, brightness change, gamma change) noises in specific areas of a facial image (eyes, mouth, nose).

I've managed to auto extract the required features from the image.

I've used `imadjust` to create contrast change (for example) on the specific features of the image and then I've blended them using `vision.AlphaBlender` and a mask of the extracted areas.

The result is the patched image below:
[image: Noised image]

What should I do in order to blend the noised feature into the original image with a natural effect which won't create a patchy image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is taking the mask of the extracted areas.
apply Gaussian noise on the mask which will create a blurring effect on the mask.

Then, apply by weighting , the blurred mask on the original image to blend the noise into the image natuarlly and that way preventing any patch effect as displayed on the attached image in my question.

Here is the code snippet:

```
% create a guassian filter
G = fspecial('gaussian', [25 25], 20);
% blur the mask - make sure your original mask is a double type
blurredMask =  imfilter(mask,G,'same');
% blend the image , the noised image and the original 
% image by weighting with the blurred mask
image = originalImage.*(1-blurredMask ) + noisedImage.*blurredMask;
```

I hope I've helped someone with my question and my answer.